# access_type=online vs offline, how to know which one to use

Tags: c#, permissions, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have implemented Google oauth2 server flow for web, the first time that user logins using his/her google account I have to use `access_type=offline` to get a refresh token and save it to database but after that `access_type=online` will be enough.
I have read that google issues limited number of refresh tokens per client (I think the limit is 25 from what I read while I was searching) so after I got the refresh token I just want to use `access_type=online`.

But before the user logs in how should I know if I have the account associated refresh token or not.

I don't want to rely on cookies as user may remove cookies, several people use the browser and cookie might not equal to the user I have its acount and ...

Any Ideas how to detect it with google oauth or something like that before showing the login button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just continue to use `access_type=offline`. It just won't give you a new refresh token after the first time. This will work until the user revokes access for your client in which case you'll have to get a new one anyway.